# WPF SkewTransform

Tags: .net, wpf

**I want to create something like this in WPF**

[image]

**To do that I have written these lines:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0"  BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0,33,0,114"   >
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="-10"/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform Y="71.691"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border  Background="BurlyWood" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="1"  BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,39,0,107"  >
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="10"/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform Y="41.82"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border  Background="BurlyWood" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**But the problem is when I resize the window, the left panel goes upper than the right panel and vise-versa. like this:**
[image]

**How can I make them stick to each other?**

Comment: May be problem arises due to RenderTransformOrigin.You haven't define Rendertransform origin in first border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should use the LayoutTransform other than the RenderTransform.

The skewed shapes should fit actually the available area, and the LayoutTransform does that.

UPDATE: the below XAML works for me:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Black" 
            Background="BurlyWood" Margin="0,50"
            >
        <Border.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="10"/>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" />
                <RotateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.LayoutTransform>
        <Border>
            <Border.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" />
            </Border.LayoutTransform>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,20">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Black"
            Background="BurlyWood"  Margin="0,50"
            >
        <Border.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="10"/>
                <RotateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.LayoutTransform>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,20">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

UPDATE 2: added the margin.

UPDATE 3: patch for the correct scaling of the content.

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it. I did the same thing except that I used `ScaleY="-1.0"`. The only problem is if the user wants to put text in it. Then it will be inverted if he uses either `ScaleX` or `ScaleY`.

Comment: @mrzli to add text we have to invert the scale to -1.0 again. Thanks Mario

Answer (score 0):

Make the vertical margins the same thickness for each `Border`. It is probably better to apply the margins to the parent `Grid` and delete the `Border` margins completely.

The *Top* margin component is different for each `Border`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Do you mean this `<Grid Margin="0,10,0,0"`? and removing all margins related to borders? if yes, it doesn't work :(